# Android Studio : IDE shows fatal error when adding a new activity to the existing project

Tags: android-studio-2.3

Studio Build: 2.3.1
Version of Gradle Plugin:2.3.1
Version of Gradle:3.3
Version of Java: OpenJDK Platform8 version 8.0.1120.6
OS: windows 10

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Open https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/tree/student/Lesson04a-Starting-New-Activities/T04a.01-Exercise-AddNewActivity   as an existing project in android studio.

2. When adding a new activity sometimes i get nullpointerexception and nothing visual happens, and some other times i get a create new activity wizard which, after clicking the Finish button, freezes and i get InvalidRefrenceException.
3. I've tried to add a new activity several times and after each attempt i got nullPointerException. On last attempt, however, the wizard showed up but after clicking the finish button, it froze and i got IllegalStateException.
4. Also when I open Android SDK manager, the SDK Tools and other tab, all the versions of sdk as well as the show details box at the bottom are unclickable.

here is the log text:

> null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.android.tools.idea.actions.NewAndroidComponentAction.actionPerformed(NewAndroidComponentAction.java:121)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:197)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:156)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:211)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$2(ActionMenuItem.java:304)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:905)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:284)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$300(TransactionGuardImpl.java:40)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:123)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:109)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
>       at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
>       at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
>       at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: I even can't access to log window, How you could see the exception?

Comment: it turns out that the path of android sdk shouldn't have whitespace. When that is fixed, this problem will also get fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me as well but only when creating the activity from the activity list. If you create the new activity from the Gallery this doesn't happen.
You find gallery here: File->New->Activity->Galery

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm4a3.jpg

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm new to android studio. Can u provide steps to create a new activity from the Gallery(preferably with screenshots). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for  the tip @Gabriel. It's a nice workaround till google fixes the bug.